# How to make a follow Ai work on a toroidal 2D grid based map

Tags: c#, grid, 2d, artificial-intelligence, console-application

I have some NPCs in a 2D matrix that wrap's around, and I have to make them follow the enemy faction NPCs using the toroidal map.

I've tried a couple of solutions but they all give me weird behaviors working only to a certain `x` or `y` value of the grid and then instead of following they go back one tile.

this is what I have right now to decide which way to go:

```cs
public Position GetNextStepTowards(Position origin, Position target)
{
    Position nextStep = new Position(0, 0);

    float dx = MathF.Abs(target.X - origin.X);
    float dy = MathF.Abs(target.Y - origin.Y);

    if (dx > mapXSize / 2) nextStep.X = -1;
    else if (dx < mapXSize / 2) nextStep.X = 1;

    if (dy > mapYSize / 2) nextStep.Y = 1;
    else if (dy < mapYSize / 2) nextStep.Y = -1;

    return nextStep;
}
```

And a Position is:

```cs
public struct Position
{
    public int X { get; set; }
    public int Y { get; set; }

    public Position(int x, int y)
    {
        this.X = x;
        this.Y = y;
    }
}
```

The NPCs can only move one cell (Moore's) therefore the movement vector should only be values between `-1` and `1`.

Thank you for the help in advance!

Comment: @user3386109 solved it, will post the solution that I came up with soon, would help if more people shared their way of doing it though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we consider the X-axis, there are two cases as shown in the diagram below:

[image]

In the first case (top) the target is to the right of the origin. In this case, moving to the right is direct, and moving to the left is toroidal.

In the second case (bottom) the target is to the left of the origin. In this case, moving to the left is direct, and moving to the right is toroidal.

So the code needs to check the relative positions of the origin and target, and then compute the left and right distances appropriately. The smaller distance determines the direction and magnitude of deltaX. The same logic applies to deltaY.

Then if deltaX and deltaY have the same magnitude, we move along the diagonal. Otherwise, we move in the direction with the larger delta.

```
private int ComputeDelta(int src, int dst, int mapSize)
{
    int increasing, decreasing;
    if (dst >= src)
    {
        increasing = dst - src;               // increasing direction is direct
        decreasing = (mapSize + src) - dst;   // decreasing direction is toroidal
    }
    else
    {
        increasing = (mapSize + dst) - src;   // increasing direction is toroidal
        decreasing = src - dst;               // decreasing direction is direct
    }

    if (increasing <= decreasing) { return  increasing; }
    else                          { return -decreasing; }
}

public Position GetNextStepTowards(Position origin, Position target)
{
    Position nextStep = new Position(0, 0);

    // compute the distances
    int dx = ComputeDelta(origin.X, target.X, mapXSize);
    int dy = ComputeDelta(origin.Y, target.Y, mapYSize);

    // keep the dominant distance, and clear the other distance
    // keep both if they're equal
    if      (dx*dx > dy*dy) { dy = 0; }
    else if (dx*dx < dy*dy) { dx = 0; }

    // normalize the distances so they are -1, 0, or 1
    nextStep.X = dx.CompareTo(0);
    nextStep.Y = dy.CompareTo(0);

    return nextStep;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for sharing this solution, works wonders, and more elegant than what I came up with

Answer (score 1):

So after a while, I came up with this solution, a bit clunky in my opinion:

```cs
public Position GetNextStepTowards(Position origin, Position target)
{
    // Returned Position
    Position nextStep = new Position(0, 0);

    int dx = target.X - origin.X;
    int dy = target.Y - origin.Y;

    // Toroidal distance
    if (dx > mapXSize / 2) dx = mapXSize - dx;
    if (dy > mapYSize / 2) dy = mapXSize - dy;

    // First verify whether the difference in positions is 
    // greater on the X or Y axis.
    // Then check if the target is lower/higher/forwards/backwards
    if (MathF.Pow(dx, 2) > MathF.Pow(dy, 2))
    {
        if (dx > 0) nextStep.X = 1;
        else if (dx < 0) nextStep.X = -1;
    }
    else if (MathF.Pow(dy, 2) > MathF.Pow(dx, 2))
    {
        if (dy > 0) nextStep.Y = 1;
        else if (dy < 0) nextStep.Y = -1;
    }

    // If the difference in the X and Y axis are the same, 
    // move diagonally
    // use CompareTo do decide what direction in specific.
    else if ((int)MathF.Pow(dx, 2) == (int)MathF.Pow(dy, 2))
    {
        nextStep.X = 1 * target.X.CompareTo(origin.X);
        nextStep.Y = 1 * target.Y.CompareTo(origin.Y);
    }

    return nextStep;
}
```